# how to parse strings from a file?

Tags: lua

I have a text file.
each block parameter is separated by a colon

```
WoodBlock : 0.886275, 0.607843, 0.25098 : 2, 2, 2 : true : -75.5656891, -11.899992, -416.506866, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 : 0, 0, 0 : 0, 0, 0

RustedBlock : 0.639216, 0.635294, 0.647059 : 2, 2, 2 : true : -35.5656891, -11.899992, -424.506866, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 : 0, 0, 0 : 0, 0, 0

StoneBlock : 0.639216, 0.635294, 0.647059 : 2, 2, 2 : true : -50.5656891, -11.899992, -425.506866, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 : 0, 0, 0 : 0, 0, 0

MetalRod : 0.388235, 0.372549, 0.384314 : 1, 3, 1 : true : -51.5656891, -11.399992, -412.506866, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 : 0, 0, 0 : 0, 0, 0
```

Each line contains information about a block. I want to make an algorithm that will work like this:

1. the first line is selected
2. the second parameter of the line is selected - the script does something with this parameter
3. the third parameter of the line is selected - the script does something with this parameter
4. the fourth parameter of the line is selected - the script does something with this parameter
5. select the fifth parameter of the line - the script does something with this parameter
   etc.

I tried using gsub but I don't know how I can select a certain line or parameter in it

Comment: Try `for line in io.lines("C:\\path\\to\\file.txt") do do_something_with(line) end` to traverse file lines.  Then `match` each line with line pattern to extract parameters.

Comment: please do more research. the manual contains all the bricks you need and you obviously haven't referred to it befor asking...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [string.gmatch](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.gmatch) to match all parameters in the colon-delimited string. The pattern used to indicate the separator is `[^:]+`, which translates to "match everything but `:` (a colon)".

Here's an example script that loops over each line, then prints each parameter.

```
for line in io.lines("blocks.txt") do
    for param in string.gmatch(line, "[^:]+") do
        print(param)
    end
end
```

Comment: You should use `string.gmatch` rather than `string.gsub`; the former is for *match*ing a pattern globally, whereas the latter is for *sub*stituting a pattern globally.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @LMD. I've made some updates.